# VBA SQL string saving short date as General date instead of short

Tags: sql, vba, datetime, ms-access

I'm trying to do something basic:
Take 2 dates [startD] and [endD] from a accdb file.
Move them forward one month each
save the new dates as short dates in the respective record.

I'm doing this all by VBA

The issue is that it is showing the correct SQL String (if i do msgbox sql) however when it saves, it is saving as a general date with time and is the wrong value!
*Note: I'm in Australia so I have a format section to make sure the date saves correctly.

I have tried using DateValue() and Formatting the date too.

```
Dim frq As Integer
Dim wks As Integer
Dim CurAcc As Integer
Dim CurAccEnd As Date
Dim Days As Integer
Dim curaccvalue As Currency
Dim cardtype As Integer
Dim cardcharged As Integer




cardtype = 0
cardcharged = 0

CurAcc = Me.ID

curraccvalue = DLookup("Acccurvalue", "Accounts", "[ID] = " & CurAcc)
Curraccend = DLookup("Accend", "Accounts", "[ID] = " & CurAcc)

frq = DLookup("freqid", "Accounts", "[ID] = " & CurAcc)

wks = DLookup("freqvalue", "tblfrequency", "FrequencyID = " & frq)
Days = wks * 7




strsql = "UPDATE Accounts SET AccStart = " & Date & " , AccEND = " &             
Curraccend     + Days & " , AccCurValue = 0.00 WHERE ID = " & CurAcc
MsgBox strsql
DoCmd.RunSQL strsql
```

Comment: A date is a number (long integer for date, double for date/time). Today is day 43495 (`? CLng(Date)`)and there is no right or wrong to this value.` Format(43495, "dddd")` will display *Wednesday*. You can format the date as `Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")` or any other format but bear in mind that the `Format` function returns a string. When storing a date as a number the display format would be in the field formatting.

Comment: Save date in a date/time field as normal, use formatting in textbox to display as short date.

Comment: If you are seeing time part, then must have Format property set as general date. Don't assign any format in table and should default to short date.

Answer (score 0):

When implicitly converting a date to a string, your regional settings are used, but in a SQL string, a date must be in the American format.

To avoid this, I suggest to do the update in just one query:

```
Dim strSql As String

strSql = "UPDATE Accounts " & _
    "INNER JOIN tblfrequency ON Accounts.freqid = tblfrequency.FrequencyID SET " & _
    "AccStart = Date(), " & _
    "AccEND = DateAdd(""w"", tblfrequency.freqvalue, Accounts.Accend), " & _
    "AccCurValue = 0.00 WHERE ID = " & Me.ID

MsgBox strSql
DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
```